# Change the variable's name only one time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If you have written a sourcecode with 10 000 row in C# and you need to change the variable's name candy into candies and the word candy is located in different position in the same  class. I wanna to change the name of the variable being located in different places only one time.

Is there a plugin or tool for Visual studio or a functionality in VS2010?

Comment: Use the Find and Replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you understand you correctly, you simply need to right-click the variable: `Refactor -> Rename...`.

Answer (score 4):

Hit `Control + Shift + H` set what you want to change and select `Replace All`.

Also you can right click over a variable and choose `Refactor -> Rename`

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Change your variable name

**2.** Click on the red rectangle

**3.** Click on the picture

**4.** Click on rename "MyVariable" in "MyVariable1"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is built-in functionality. Change the name of the variable in its declaration line and a popup button will appear right next to it. Click it and choose Rename 'candy' to 'candies'. This will perform full rename wherever the variable is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the variable and choose Refactor->Rename from the menu, it's the most save way to accomplish it.

for vb.net it's Rename directly...

Answer (score 0):

Edit->Replace and tick the "match whole word only" box?

Comment: Could cause problems, if `candy` is used within some other variable names, like `candyColor`.

Comment: @Matthias Koch - that's exactly why I said "Match whole word only".

Answer (score 0):

You could use CodeRush Xpress, a free tool by DevExpress that allows easy variable\class\method renaming and has lots of other features. Grab it here: http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/